# Private member variable must be prefixed with an underscore

Tags: php, syntax, phpstorm, psr-2

In PhpStorm, I am adding some code to a class. The class has a private property defined via this line:

```
private $pdfService
```

... but the line is underlined by the IDE's syntax checker. Hovering over the line shows the following error message:

> Private member variable "jobRepository" must be prefixed with an
>   underscore

This is annoying, since using an underscore to indicate privacy on a property is explicitly discouraged by [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

**Is there a simple way to update the syntax checking so that it adheres to PSR-2 in regards to this rule?**

====

Edit: Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: To start with: show exact message screenshot please. I do not remember such requirement. Must be either some disabled-by-default inspection or 3rd party inspection.

Comment: OK ... so as you can see it comes from `phpcs` .. which is **PHP Code Sniffer**. Adjust your Code Sniffer rules or choose different Coding standard (at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Quality tools | PHP Code Sniffer validation`) where you do not have such requirement.

Comment: @LazyOne: Thank you. This option was directly under `PHP` for me for some reason, but the rest of the route you described worked perfectly.

Comment: We must be using different IDE versions -- I'm on vanilla 2018.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole message starts with `phpcs:` .. which means that it comes from **PHP Code Sniffer** which you have configured and enabled integration for this project.

Adjust your Code Sniffer rules accordingly or choose different Coding standard (at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Quality tools | PHP Code Sniffer validation`) where you do not have such requirement.

[image]